# Print custom message when there is no data in table return by kusto query

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql, monitor, kusto-explorer, kqlmagic

I am working on a dashboard, where in backend Kusto query are running and plot a graph on dashboard based on the results.

I am trying to print a custom message like,

| extend CustomColumn=iff(isempty(expectedExpiration),"Expiration data is not available for this ",expectedExpiration)

i tried isempty, isnull, isNaN function as well but I am not getting this custom message as an output.

Can you help in finding what is going wrong here or I am missing something?

Explained in prob statement

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It will be helpful if you can share some sample data @itshemant09

Comment: sure, i will update the question with example